How to do consecutive subtraction of adjacent columns and return the result concatenated in cell with comma separator?
I have following data which has the Product ID and their order dates in each column in descending order.

I want to subtract column D from column C then return the result in column B, then subtract column E from column D and return result in column B with previous result separated by comma. And this will be repeated till last filled column. Once that's done i can pull the formula down for the rest of the rows.
I did the manual calculation for couple of rows. But I am trying to do this for larger data. The result should like this:

Each arrow color belongs the result of subtraction in column B. For example, for red arrow, column D is subtracted from column C and the result(8) is highlighted by color Red in column B.
Thank you.

AFAIK with formula you cannot color the content of the cell

Thanks for mentioning that, but I colored it for the visual representation. I am not expecting the result to be colored. But its helpful to know that it will be hard/ impossible to do that in the future. Thanks for your insight.

Using TEXTJOIN,FILTER and DROP:
=LET(rng,C2:M2,flt,FILTER(rng,rng<>""),TEXTJOIN(",",,DROP(flt,,-1)-DROP(flt,,1)))



Thank you so much Scott. Its working but only for the row 2. When I drag the formula for the next row, it gives "Value not available error". It might be due to empty cells, because when I added zero, it returned cell with 0. It would be great if you could help on that one since I plan to use that formula for multiple row and editing it for every row won't be feasible.
